# Unable to click on an element through Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

On google flights page, I want to click on the right arrow (increase number of days) at the bottom of the dialog (attached image). The second click gives me `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` error.

Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://www.google.fr/flights'
driver.get(url)
elem1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='gws-flights-form__date-content']")[0]
elem1.click()
a = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//<span[@class='gws-flights-dialog__calendar-duration-flipper-increase']")))
a.click()
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the *right arrow* to increase number of days at the bottom of the dialog instead of using `visibility_of_element_located()` method you need to use **`element_to_be_clickable()`** method and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.gws-flights-form__departure-input[data-flt-ve='departure_date'] div.gws-flights-form__next"))).click()
  ```
- `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-flt-ve='departure_date' and contains(@class,'gws-flights-form__departure-input')]//div[@class='gws-flights-form__next']"))).click()
  ```

Comment: It still gives me selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-flt-ve='departure_date' and contains(@class,'gws-flights-form__departure-input')]/div[@class='gws-flights-form__next']"))).click()

Comment: @PittLee How about the _CSS-SELECTOR_?

Comment: I got this error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" jstcache="5760" jsaction="jsl._" class="gws-flights-form__next" jsan="7.gws-flights-form__next,0.aria-hidden,0.role,0.tabindex,22.jsaction"></div> is not clickable at point (903, 156). Other element would receive the click: <div class="gws-flights__glass-pane" id="flt-glass" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" jsaction="jsl._" jstcache="5646"
style="display: block;"></div>

Comment: The issue seems related to Chrome driver.  I tried your solution in firefox, and it worked.  Really appreciate your help!